# Where are the packages on Visual Studio Mac 7.3.3?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

After a update on the VS, and clean all my projects and can't see where are the packages downloaded/stored. Are not in my project(s) folder anywhere. However, I can build and run ok.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core apps, NuGet packages are restored to global cache, not in solution folders.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about NuGet packages. If you are using a .NET Core or .NET Standard project then the NuGet packages would be in the `~/.nuget/packages/` folder.

Comment: That is correct. Please add as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find those in the global cache:

```
~/.nuget/packages/
```